# Does converting your Kuva Lich count as killing it?

Tags: warframe

Kuva Liches steal some of your resources when you complete a mission in their territory.  It has been stated that killing your Kuva Lich is the only way to recover this stolen loot.

Additionally, I find it implied, if not outright stated, that you can only have 1 Kuva Lich at a time.

Both of these points have significant impacts on the subject of killing your Kuva Lich vs converting it.  Namely: if you choose to convert your Kuva Lich instead of killing it, does this count as "completing" the lich?  Does it let you start another one?  Does it return your resources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, converting a Lich counts as completing it, as such you will be able to get a new lich, and you will receive all stolen goods back.

If your lich has an ephemera, you will get it regardless of your choice, but you will only get its weapon if you kill it.

Source: personal experience, and the [wiki](https://warframe.fandom.com/wiki/Kuva_Lich)

Comment: So there's really no difference between converting/killing, besides the difference in the outcome ally/kuvaweapon, correct?

Comment: @senpai that is correct, yes. Killing them grants the weapon they're using, but converting them will turn them into an "ally".

Comment: Worth noting, if they have an ephemera, you WILL get the ephemera with either option.

Answer (score -1):

Let me correct [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/359720/):
If you kill your lich you will get all stolen things back + ephemera (if your lich has one) + weapon but you won't be able to trade any of these.

And if you convert it still you will get all stolen things back + ephemera + your lich will become your ally but you will not get the weapon, but... your lich, ephemera, and weapon will be tradable.

Source: Personal experience